# wrapping a long string in multiple lines starting from a position

Tags: linux, file, shell, awk

I have a file that looks this:

```html
FirstSentences1  bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkjezfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsdfsljfklj
SecondSentences2 fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgijgoejrgrjgiorjofgjeirjgoergd
.
.
.
NthhhSentencesN  klkdlffjsldfsljflsfjlskfjldkjflsfjlfkdjfdfjojjij
```

I Have to get the following output :

```html
FirstSentences1  bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkje
FirstSentences1  zfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsd
FirstSentences1  fsljfklj
SecondSentences2 fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgi
SecondSentences2 jgoejrgrjgiorjofgjei
SecondSentences2 rjgoergd
.
.
.
NthhhSentencesN  klkdlffjsldfsljflsfj
NthhhSentencesN  lskfjldkjflsfjlfkdjf
NthhhSentencesN  dfjojjij
```

Explanation :

for example the first line :

```html
FirstSentences1  bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkjezfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsdfsljfklj
```

We take the string "bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkjezfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsdfsljfklj" and we wrapp it when the length is equal to 20

Do you know a way to get this ?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: and are you really repeating `FirstSentences1` at the front of the line, or is that just to illustrate that first sentence is now on 3 lines? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes I am really repeating the "FirstSentences1" in each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a short script utilizing *string indexes* and a nested loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i len=${2:-20}     ## take length as 2nd arg (filename is 1st)

while read -r line; do      ## read each line
    while [ ${#line} -gt 0 ]; do            ## if characters remain
        printf "%s\n" "${line:0:$((len))}"  ## print len chars
        line="${line:$((len))}"             ## strip len chars from line
    done
done < "$1"
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/longsent.txt
bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkjezfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsdfsljfklj
fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgijgoejrgrjgiorjofgjeirjgoergd
```

**Example Use/Output**

Wrapping at *default* `20-chars` per-line:

```
$ bash wrap.sh dat/longsent.txt
bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkje
zfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsd
fsljfklj
fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgi
jgoejrgrjgiorjofgjei
rjgoergd
```

Wrapping at `10` characters per-line:

```
$ bash wrap.sh dat/longsent.txt 10
bfjkjhdfhi
zhfzibfkje
zfzfiuzehf
izdjfldfsd
fsljfklj
fjlskdjfjo
ijrgeojrgi
jgoejrgrjg
iorjofgjei
rjgoergd
```

**note:** you should validate that `len` is greater than `0`, and you can add `|| test -n "$line"` to the first while clause to accommodate non-POSIX line ending on the last line (omitted for brevity).

---

**Including the Line Prefix**

If your datafile includes the prefixes, (e.g. `FirstSentence1`, `...`) and you need to include those in your output, you simply add the read of the `prefix` before `line` and output `prefix` (with some sane field width, left-justified) before each wrapped line. e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i len=${2:-20}     ## take length as 2nd arg (filename is 1st)
declare -i wdth=22          ## set min field width for prefix (so cols align)

while read -r prefix line; do      ## read each line
    while [ ${#line} -gt 0 ]; do   ## if characters remain
        ## print len chars w/prefix width set to wdth, left-justified
        printf "%-*s %s\n" $wdth "$prefix" "${line:0:$((len))}"
        line="${line:$((len))}"    ## strip len chars from line
    done
done < "$1"
```

**Example Input File w/Prefix**

```
$ cat dat/longsentpfx.txt
FirstSentence1   bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkjezfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsdfsljfklj
SecondSentences2 fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgijgoejrgrjgiorjofgjeirjgoergd
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash wrap.sh dat/longsentpfx.txt
FirstSentence1         bfjkjhdfhizhfzibfkje
FirstSentence1         zfzfiuzehfizdjfldfsd
FirstSentence1         fsljfklj
SecondSentences2       fjlskdjfjoijrgeojrgi
SecondSentences2       jgoejrgrjgiorjofgjei
SecondSentences2       rjgoergd

$ bash wrap.sh dat/longsentpfx.txt 10
FirstSentence1         bfjkjhdfhi
FirstSentence1         zhfzibfkje
FirstSentence1         zfzfiuzehf
FirstSentence1         izdjfldfsd
FirstSentence1         fsljfklj
SecondSentences2       fjlskdjfjo
SecondSentences2       ijrgeojrgi
SecondSentences2       jgoejrgrjg
SecondSentences2       iorjofgjei
SecondSentences2       rjgoergd
```

Let me know if you have additional questions.

**note:** to set the width to exactly one character past the longest `prefix`, you would need to read all `prefix` values before actually writing the wrapped lines to find the longest width and then add `+1`. If your datafile is short, you could read the prefixes and lines into a pair of *indexed arrays* and scan the lengths from the prefix array first, if the datafile is huge, you could scan the file twice (not optimal), or you can just set some predetermined width as done above.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but What about the first string "Firstsentences1, SecondSentences2...." do you have any way to deal with them

Comment: Oh, OK, I see you actually want `FirstSentence1` and `SecondSentences2` as *prefixes*. I thought you just put that there to distinguish the sentences were wrapped. Sure, just add `prefix` to the `read` and `printf` statements. e.g. `while read -r prefix line; do` ... `printf "%s %s\n" "$prefix" "${line:0:$((len))}"`

Answer (score 2):

Using `substr`:

```
awk '{ for(i=0;i<length($2);i=i+20) print $1,substr($2,i,20) }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you can do:

```
awk '{n=patsplit($2, a, /.{1,20}/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1, a[i] }' file
```